# link to another answer from within your answer (on the same post)

Tags: feature-request

Any way to link another person's answer to the same post from within your answer to the same post?

I tried the following:

I took the share link of the OP's post put it in the browser tab to get the complete (redirected) url. I copied that url and added it as a link to my post. However, on clicking on that link, I was expecting the web page to scroll. Instead I got a round trip, and the page refreshed.

Comment: Use the URL from the `share` link.

Comment: The reason that happens is because the full answer permalink consists of the answer ID both as part of the URL path and as the hash fragment. It would certainly be nice to be able to link to another answer via the hash fragment, but then you have to account for things like pagination if the question has more than 30 answers.

Comment: You have done [well here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19652963/2345913)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn agreed! not as simple as I thought it would be...

Comment: The way you describe works for me: the browser jumps to the anchor and doesn't refresh the page. You could improve the Q showing an explicit example of what did you try.